# IndexError: tuple index out of range. Accessing column in specific row

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, int, typeerror

I'm getting a IndexError issue that I cannot fix.  What I am trying to do is iterate through rows of data and compare a specific column in one row to the same column in a different row.  If they are the same it should put them in the badBucket otherwise it goes in to a goodBucket.

Here is my code:

```
XDFDF =pd.DataFrame(XDF)
ct1 = 0
ct2 = 0
goodBucket = []
badBucket = []
duplicate = False
for row in XDFDF.iterrows():
    for row2 in XDFDF.iterrows():
        if ct1 != ct2:
            if row[6] == row2[6]:
                badBucket.append(row2)
                duplicate = True
            else:
                goodBucket.append(row2)
        ct2 += 1
    if duplicate:
        badBucket.append(row)
        duplicate = False
    ct1 += 1
```

Note: XDFDF is a relatively big pandas DataFrame with 6 columns (0,1,2,3,4,5,6).

My Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john_crowley/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/Recipes.py", line 118, in <module>
    if row[6] == row2[6]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note: line 118 is the line where 'if row[5] == row[5]' is typed.

If anyone has a resolution to the specific issue at hand to resolve the IndexError your help would be greatly appreciated, or any comments on improving code would be appreciated as well.  If you have any questions please let me know and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Given your description, `row[ct1]` is already an integer value. What do you expect `row[ct1][6] == row2[ct2][6]` to do?

Comment: @iBug I feel like @Fletchy1995 is using `row[ct1]` to (incorrectly) access the `ct1`th row of `XDFDF` in an attempt to compare different rows only. Is that right, @Fletchy1995?

Comment: Can you post example input of a few rows that reproduces the probem?

Comment: Yes both the above are correct @iBug and user1093967.  I have adjusted my code but I am now getting a new error which is an IndexError.  I have attempted to adjust the number '6' to lower numbers but I had no avail in getting a solution yet.

Comment: @Fletchy1995 I have additional questions about what you're trying to do. Should `badBucket` contain each of the duplicated rows, or the duplicated row repeated each time there's a match (what you're doing). Take the simple case where your `DataFrame` has 3 rows, all equal on the relevant column. Your current algorithm aims to populate `badBucket` with 9 elements: second row, third row, first row, first row, third row, second row, first row, second row, and third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to code the logic for identifying duplicates yourself; use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) (predicated on column 6 with `keep=False` from what I gather you're trying to do) instead.

Comment: when predicating column 6 should I be using the column name Ex: ['Column6'] or should I just use an integer Ex. 6.  For example when typing 'code'XDFDFdrop = pd.DataFrame.duplicated(XDFDF, subset=6)'code' I get a 'KeyError: Int64Index([6], dtype ='int64')'

Comment: Just curious do you know if there is a way to do the opposite of that?

Answer (score 2):

`iterrows()` return not just a row as you expect, but the tuple of row index and row itself. So this tuple of two values doesn't have index 6, so you get the Exception: "tuple index out of range" (pay attention to **tuple**)

If you don't need row index, you can use any name, the best one is _ which is a correct variable name and it is used in python to mark variabales that you don't need. So the correct loop code is

```
for _, row in XDFDF.iterrows():
    for _, row2 in XDFDF.iterrows():
```

Or if the index is just a sequence of integers from 0, you can use it instead of ct1 and ct2 if you assume ct2 should be reset to 0 at the begining of each loop for row2 (by the way there is no `ct2 = 0` before this loop which might be a logical error). To ensure the index is really like needed I would recomend force reset_index(drop=True) before the loop. Otherwise it would be difficult to find problem if you would manipulate with data before and break the index sequence.

But in fact if you only need to find duplicate values (you code is not doing exactly that but I'm not sure if this is assumed or a logical error in the code) you can use pandas `drop_duplicates` which will do all the work for you. So we can create column "unique" and set True for those indexes which aren't dropped as duplicate

```
XDFDF["unique"] = False
indexes_of_unique = XDFDF.loc[:, 6].drop_duplicates(keep=False).index
XDFDF.loc[indexes_of_unique, "unique"] = True
```

This part is the most important `XDFDF.loc[:, 6].drop_duplicates(keep=False).index`. It gets the column 6, drops duplicate values (by default it keeps one duplicate value, but keep=False forces drop all values which have duplicates). So now we have the indexes of unique values and we can mark them. Important note, that indexes in pandas aren't guaranteed to be uniuqe, so I'd recomend to make `XDFDF.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` to ensure there wouldn't be logical collisions with duplicate indexes.

Comment: This is interesting I did not know this.  Thank you so much.  However I am now getting a TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <'class 'pandas.core.base.Index'> with these indexers [6] of class 'int'> . Any ideas?  I'm going to try to do some troubleshooting but if you have a quick fix that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Are you sure you have indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as ints, not strings? You may try to use "6" instead of 6. Or if that doesn't work just print the XDFDF.columns to see if they are really 0, 1, 2, 3... and print(type(XDFDF.columns[6])) to check the type.

Comment: Yes I checked that @leonid.  For clarification the return types were strings but they were the titles I set them in the code.  7 columns total.